# Create a thread for each element in list

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

I am trying to make for each item in my list a separate thread.

How can i achieve this?

List contains 10-20 urls. Which i need to download,parse and insert to DB

So what i am trying to do:

```
urls = {'url1,url2,url3'}
def get_and_insert(xml):
    try:
        get = requests.get(xml)
        parsed = xmltodict.parse(get.text)
        //upload info to DB and so on..


for each in urls:
      threading.Thread(target=get_and_insert(each)).start()
```

But python still going one by one each url. without threading.

How to do it? Or maybe someone can share an example with async.

Comment: Your threads do nothing since you are calling the function once yourself for each url.

Comment: So how can i create a thread for each element?

Comment: Pass `get_and_insert` as `target`, and `each` as `args` to [`Thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)

Comment: wYou need: threading.Thread(target=get_and_insert, args=(each,))    <——- note edit.

Comment: in that case i got strange error. if i do:   threading.Thread(target=get_and_insert(),args=each).start().   I got this error: TypeError: get_and_insert() takes 1 positional argument but 35 were given

Comment: Thanks @quamrana seems like i got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in

```
threading.Thread(target=get_and_insert(each)).start()
```

I pass argument to thread incorrectly

Correct way to do it:

```
threading.Thread(target=get_and_insert,args=(each,)).start()
```

Since args should get tuple

Now it works

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted, so people can see that a question already has  a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the arguments in args, don't forget to close the threads!

```
threads = []
urls = {'url1,url2,url3'}

for each in urls:
    t = threading.Thread(target=get_and_insert, args=(each,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
    print(t.is_alive())
```